# How to fix State monoid type in the following code

Tags: scala, scalaz, monoids

I am using State monoid to update the state of an object as listed in Functional and Reactive Domain modeling book while working CQRS. As I understand, if you do not want to return any value, you can just have () as below. But from me, I keep getting "Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to the expected type A". These lines below
State { s => (updateState(r, s), ()) } give me this error. 
As I understand, this code used to work before, when the book was published, I am guessing due to recent changes in Scalaz it is broken now. I just started looking at Scalaz couple days ago and wondering if any Scalaz experts can chime in.

I have already tried to make State[Map[String, Account], A] to State[Map[String, Account], Unit], but this breaks exec.

```
object PureInterpreter {
  import Event._
  import Commands.Command
  type MapState[A] = State[Map[String, Account], A]

  val step = new (Event ~> MapState) {
    override def apply[A](fa: Event[A]): MapState[A] = fa match {
      case o @ Opened(no, _, _) =>
        State { s => (updateState(o, s), no) }

      case c @ Closed(_, _) =>
        State { s => (updateState(c, s), ()) }

      case d @ Debited(_, _) =>
        State { s => (updateState(d, s), ()) }

      case r @ Credited(_, _) =>
        State { s => (updateState(r, s), ()) }
    }
  }

  def interpret[A](c: Command[A], state: Map[String, Account] = Map.empty): Map[Strin  g, Account] =
    c.foldMap(step).exec(state)

}
```

Comment: I believe you are missing something. The type error looks reasonable and don't think switching scalaz version could help. 

What do you mean by `do not want to return any value`?  Probably you actually want to return the same value unchanged? If you really want to abrupt the computation and report an error then you can't do it without changing signature.